# How to choose an array entry at random in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make this website to practice my programming.

```
<html>
    <title>VidVoter</title>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <div id="welcome">Welcome to VidVoter!</div>


        <a href="file://localhost/Users/alihashemi/Desktop/vidvoter.html">
            <div id="vote1">Vote for this video</div>
        </a>


        <a href="file://localhost/Users/alihashemi/Desktop/vidvoter.html">
            <div id="vote2">Vote for this video</div>
        </a>
    </head>

    <?php
    $videos = array("xrCTiImIWk4" , "WCpfVPY4J6I" , "__2ABJjxzNo" , "y7tI1E6kp0o" , "-NSL_DgwCYw"); 
    $rand = array_rand($videos);
    $rand_key = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : $rand;
    ?>


    <p>

            <h1><iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php .$rand_key.?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></h1>

            <h2><iframe id="vid2" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php .$rand_key.?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><h2>


    </p>
</html>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to randomly choose a video from an array of videos and place it on the site. Would you please help me out?

Comment: Do you even have a server installed?  The fact that you are using file urls leads me to believe you do not.

Answer (score 2):

As DevZer0 commented, array_rand() returns an array key, not it's value. In your example you would want

```
$rand_key = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : $video[$rand];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried..

```
$rand_key = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : $rand[0];
```

Comment: If you are picking only one entry, array_rand() returns the key for a random entry.